# Getting a flash video on a new page load at position it was at on the last page

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash, cookies, actionscript

I have a an unobtrusive flash video looping in the background of a website, it is not essential to navigation - it is purely cosmetic.

The flash video loops every 30 seconds.

As this video is on all pages, it jumps back to the start when a new page is loaded.

Is there an actionscript / javascript way to get it to remember the position it got to on the old page so it can start there on the new page?

I do know that this can be accomplished by loading the flash movie in a frame as well as by having the subsequent pages load the contents in AJAX but I was hoping not to go down this route.

I have seen other people ask the question and allude to the solution but they only posted that they got it to work without saying how.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this won't be possible using only actionscript/javascript as even if you can skip to a specific frame (which I'm sure you can do with actionscript) you'll have to get that value to it somehow, which would require storing the value between pages. I guess that *could* be done by wrapping the whole thing in a frame and running js in the parent frame, but I get the impression you wouldn't want to do that either. Otherwise however you'll have to use AJAX or something to send the value to the server and store/return it using a server side language.

Comment: My thought was that upon loading the current time is stored.

The mod of the difference between the current and last page load time will be the position at which the video needs to start but that doesn't account for a delay in loading so it would be off by about 2 seconds. That is, if the video is 30 seconds long and the difference between the last page loading and the current page loading is 45 seconds, 45 mod 30 = 15, so it should start 15 seconds in.

Answer (score 0):

Flash SharedObject would help you. The link below shows how to use it.

[SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html)

You have to write currentframe of video to the sharedobject, and when it show up again get sharedobject and read the value for currentframe.